# Powershell regex replace - use $1 as dictionary key

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, powershell-2.0

I am trying to find regex pattern in a string and replace it using a hash table. First example works fine and I get "$$oldstring$$ $$oldstring$$" as result. I cannot figure out how to pass the '$1' into a hash table as the key in order to replace it with the value corresponding to that key in my hash.

Here is my code:

```
$hashtable = @{'$$oldstring$$' = 'newstring'}

$testString = '$$oldstring$$'

$replaced = [regex]::Replace($testString, '(\$\$(.*?)\$\$)', '$1 $1')
$replaced

$replaced2 = [regex]::Replace($testString, '(\$\$(.*?)\$\$)', $hashtable.Get_Item($1))
$replaced2
```

And the output:

```
$$oldstring$$ $$oldstring$$

Exception calling "get_Item" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
```

I understand that $hashtable.Get_Item($1) is not valid syntax and $1 is null here, but can't seem to figure out how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out on my own, had to use a script block like this:

```
$replaced2 = [regex]::Replace($testString, '(\$\$(.*?)\$\$)', { $hashtable.Get_Item($args[0].Value) } )
```

More info here:
http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions#Match_Evaluator